# Bitbucket Event Payload Not As Expected

Tags: php, json, jwt, bitbucket, webhooks

I am interested in getting bitbucket event payloads as they occur (e.g repo push, pull request created) in my application. I have all the necessary stuff ready (app descriptor, webhooks etc.)

I am able to get the event payload in event controller/handler when bitbucket sends event payload on that. But the payload is not as expected. See [event payload docs](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/event-payloads/?_ga=2.63275622.858340325.1595247585-781994746.1586523469#:%7E:text=When%20you%20have%20a%20webhook,webhook%20whenever%20that%20event%20occurs.&text=For%20Bitbucket%20to%20send%20event,public%20certificate%20authority%20has%20signed.)  for what should I be getting.

But, what I actually get is something like this

```
Array(
        [ciphertext] => someciphertext
        [encrypted_key] => yJGtBQD3x1oHxaB
        [header] => Array
            (
                [alg] => PBES2-HS512+A256KW
                [kid] => ari:cloud:bitbucket::app/{259e10da-4427-4b0}/test-app
                [p2c] => 8192
                [p2s] => TM6HLQpGaYg
            )
    
        [iv] => MtspXopJ4A
        [protected] => eyJlbmEyIn0
        [tag] => N4d5b4KsKhc
    )
```

This seems like some encrypted data. Any pointers what it actually is and if it is encrypted how can I decrypt it.